# How to increase the text size in assembly graphics?

Tags: assembly, x86, masm, dosbox

Here is my code.

```
.model small
.stack
.data

.code

;setting video mode
mov ah,0
mov al,12h
int 10h


;setting cursor position
mov ah,02h  
mov dh,10    ;row 
mov dl,40     ;column
int 10h

mov ah,09h
mov bl,0eh   ;colour
mov cx,1      ;no.of times
mov al,'B'      ;print B
int 10h   

 mov ah,4ch
int 21h

end
```

The output of the given code is

[image: Output of the given code]

As you can see the character size on the display with the video mode of 12h. I want to know that what is the function code and parameters to increase the size of the character.

Answer (score 4):

The size of your character is determined by the video mode. From http://lateblt.tripod.com/bit24.txt:

```
00: 40x25 Black and White text (CGA,EGA,MCGA,VGA)
01: 40x25 16 color text (CGA,EGA,MCGA,VGA)
02: 80x25 16 shades of gray text (CGA,EGA,MCGA,VGA)
03: 80x25 16 color text (CGA,EGA,MCGA,VGA)
04: 320x200 4 color graphics (CGA,EGA,MCGA,VGA)
05: 320x200 4 color graphics (CGA,EGA,MCGA,VGA)
06: 640x200 B/W graphics (CGA,EGA,MCGA,VGA)
07: 80x25 Monochrome text (MDA,HERC,EGA,VGA)
08: 160x200 16 color graphics (PCjr)
09: 320x200 16 color graphics (PCjr)
0A: 640x200 4 color graphics (PCjr)
0D: 320x200 16 color graphics (EGA,VGA)
0E: 640x200 16 color graphics (EGA,VGA)
0F: 640x350 Monochrome graphics (EGA,VGA)
10: 640x350 16 color graphics (EGA or VGA with 128K)
    640x350 4 color graphics (64K EGA)
11: 640x480 B/W graphics (MCGA,VGA)
12: 640x480 16 color graphics (VGA)
13: 320x200 256 color graphics (MCGA,VGA)
```

Comment: You could vastly enhance this answer by including for each video mode the number of character rows on screen. Ultimately this number tells how large the characters will be.